Mixed Effects Model Versus Generalized Estimating Equation For limited repeated measures and a non-normal distribution
My data set has patients longitudinally measured with a numeric outcome that is left skewed. Roughly half the patients have 2 or fewer measurements while the rest have 3 or more. I also see significant patterns with respect to therapy groups in the data set that influence results (pre-treatment,receiving treatment, recently completed treatment, and 6 months removed from treatment).
My approach for now is to utilize GEE with clusters for 4 different treatment statuses (pre-treatment,receiving treatment, recently completed treatment, and 6 months removed from treatment) as opposed to using clusters for patient specific id because trends can't be formed for id's with limited samples. Also a lack of normal distribution for the outcome violates assumptions needed for linear mixed effects.
I have a couple of basic questions with model selection practices:

Is there a minimum number of repeated measures needed per patient to utilized linear mixed effects reliably? Would patient specific random effects captured be unreliable with limited samples (some patients not having repeated measurements)?
If you created clusters based on therapy exposure status each having 20+ samples with GEEs, does that remove treatment status as a potential covariate for subsequent models?

Thanks, if there are related entries to be referred to that would be much appreciated.
